# Does opening two slits instead of one reduce the number of photons arriving at a some locations in the bell shape?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference, superposition

Here is something that's been bothering me about quantum superposition: 
I'd like to know if experiments suggest that opening two slits would decrease the number of photons falling on a region of destructive interference at the screen than it would've with just a single slit.

In other words, in a region previously observed to have say $\langle x \rangle _{1}$ number of photons arrive at it with one slit open, now that same spot sits in an area of destructive interference w/ two slits open. Let the number of photons arriving now be $\langle y \rangle _{2}$.

Given both experiments run for N number of photons ejected, do we observe $\langle y \rangle_{2}<\langle x \rangle _{1}$ for the same $N$ in some spots?

Comment: Yes. See [Quantum Behavior](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_37.html) in the Feynman Lectures.

Comment: @NickD I'm coming from there. I took his word for it, but I want to see the experiment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As you can see from the image below, opening up another slit changes the intensity distribution. There are regions in the second image (double slit) where no light reaches even if it did so in the first one (single slit).

[image]Image from [Universe Today](https://www.universetoday.com/83380/double-slit-experiment/)